# How do i get permissions attached with AWS policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

Is there any way to get AWS permissions attached with a policy.
Currently, I am getting a list of attached policies through boto3 "list_policies."
My target is to get permissions attached with each policy.

Answer (score 0):

Using boto3 you can get access to the policy document, which you can parse to get the permissions.

So, iterate the list_policies response and call get_policy_version with the Arn and DefaultVersionId to get the policy document.

> https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_policies
>   https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_policy_version